Problem with the package hyperref

Hello I want to link by a \hyperref each question of the exercise has its solution only those numbered in \arabic but by executing it there is no link which appears thank you for helping me to solve this problem.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsfonts, latexsym, mathrsfs, calrsfs}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[bb=boondox]{mathalfa}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz, tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtcbox{\boxa}{on line, boxrule=1pt, left=0pt, right=0pt, top=0pt, bottom=0pt, colframe=blue, colback=white, boxrule=1.5pt, coltext=blue, fontupper=\itshape\bfseries\large}
\newtcbox{\boxb}{on line, left=0pt, right=0pt, top=0pt, bottom=0pt, colframe=green, colback=white, boxrule=1pt, coltext=green, arc=0mm}
\newtcbox{\boxc}{on line, boxrule=0pt, left=0pt, right=0pt, top=0pt, bottom=0pt, colframe=green, colback=white, boxrule=1pt, coltext=green, arc=0mm}

\let\olditem\item
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\item}{%
  \ifnum \@enumdepth =\@ne 
    \olditem
    \hypertarget{item-\theenumi}{$\blacktriangleright$}
  \else
    \olditem 
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\boxa{\arabic*}, font=\itshape\bfseries\Large, leftmargin=*}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\boxb{\alph*}, font=\itshape\bfseries, leftmargin=0.5em, labelsep=0.5em, before=\leavevmode\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}, align=left}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=\boxc{\roman*)}, font=\itshape\bfseries\large, leftmargin=*}


\begin{document}
\section*{Exercise}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First question
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item First question
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item First question
      \item second question
      \item Third question
    \end{enumerate}
    \item second question
    \item Third question
  \end{enumerate}
  \item second question
  \item Third question 
\end{enumerate}
\section*{Solution to the exercise}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First answer
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item First answer
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item First answer
      \item second answer
      \item Third answer
    \end{enumerate}
    \item second answer
    \item Third answer
  \end{enumerate}
  \item second answer
  \item Third answer
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}


you've not added any links. you've only got code to create hypertargets. you also need to make a link to link to the target.

To do it by hand you must add both a target and a link, just as you would to make a link on a web page. \hypertarget adds only a target. (How should it know where to put a link or links?)
But why do it by hand at all? Why not just use cross-references? Then you get linking out-of-the-box. You may, however, want to switch off hyperref's red boxing ;).
Minimised code since most of your preamble was irrelevant:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtcbox{\boxa}{on line, boxrule=1pt, left=0pt, right=0pt, top=0pt, bottom=0pt, colframe=blue, colback=white, boxrule=1.5pt, coltext=blue, fontupper=\itshape\bfseries\large}
\newtcbox{\boxb}{on line, left=0pt, right=0pt, top=0pt, bottom=0pt, colframe=green, colback=white, boxrule=1pt, coltext=green, arc=0mm}
\newtcbox{\boxc}{on line, boxrule=0pt, left=0pt, right=0pt, top=0pt, bottom=0pt, colframe=green, colback=white, boxrule=1pt, coltext=green, arc=0mm}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\boxa{\arabic*}, font=\itshape\bfseries\Large, leftmargin=*}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\boxb{\alph*}, font=\itshape\bfseries, leftmargin=0.5em, labelsep=0.5em, before=\leavevmode\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}, align=left}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=\boxc{\roman*)}, font=\itshape\bfseries\large, leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}
\section*{Exercise}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item[\ref{ex:first}] First answer
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item First question
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item First question
          \item second question
          \item Third question
        \end{enumerate}
      \item second question
      \item Third question
    \end{enumerate}
  \item[\ref{ex:second}] second answer
  \item[\ref{ex:third}] Third answer
\end{enumerate}
\section*{Solution to the exercise}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item\label{ex:first} First question
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item First answer
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item First answer
          \item second answer
          \item Third answer
        \end{enumerate}
      \item second answer
      \item Third answer
    \end{enumerate}
  \item\label{ex:second} second question
  \item\label{ex:third} Third question
\end{enumerate}
\clearpage
hello
\end{document}


Thank "cfr" you for your response. Yes indeed I changed \let\olditem\item ... by that but it doesn't work correctly. \makeatletter \newcounter{exerciseItem} \newcounter{solutionItem} \let\olditem\item \renewcommand{\item}{% \ifnum @enumdepth =@ne \ifnum\value{exerciseItem}>0% \stepcounter{exerciseItem} \olditem \label{ex:item\theexerciseItem} See solution \hyperref[sol:item\theexerciseItem]{here}. \else \stepcounter{solutionItem} \olditem \label{sol:item\thesolutionItem} See exercise \hyperref[ex:item\thesolutionItem]{here}. \fi \else \olditem % \fi } \newcommand{\startExercise}{% \setcounte

I don't understand.  Is this an answer to your original question?  "doesn't work correctly" says otherwise.  Is it a comment on cfr's answer?  Then it should be a comment there, but cfr didn't use \let\olditem\item.  Is it a comment about your original question and cfr's answer?  Then it should be an edit to your question, but it's not clear what you mean by "by that".

Yes it's a comment. I changed my code not that of cfr

I couldn't write a long comment, I'm new to this group . I expected that you wouldn't help me give me feedback on the way I express myself, thank you anyway

@user321215 I'm afraid I don't understand either. The code you have in your comment isn't the code I proposed. I'm not really sure what to say. I mean, you're not using my code. is there a problem with my answer I need to fix? did you try the exact code I posted? please test that in a new document and see if it works on its own.

@user321215 the way you're trying to do this is way more complicated than it needs to be. you shouldn't need to use \hyperref or \stepcounter at all here.

@cfr yes your code is correct but I want to do it automatically for the entire document, especially for documents already written and I don't want to do that by hand

@user321215 that wasn't at all clear from your question. I'd suggest asking a new question and linking this one. I don't think it makes sense to discuss in comments why code completely unrelated to the code I posted doesn't work. but you can automate the addition of cross-referencing information unless there's some reason not to.
